# Webcam for Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am looking for a USB webcam that is compatible with Windows Server 2003.  Most of the ones that I have found only specify XP/Vista.

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'll venture a guess that you won't find one. You should be able to use anything with an XP driver on Server 2K3 though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be very surprised if an XP camera wouldn't work with W2K3 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have used several different webcams, including a couple of "no-name" brands, on Server 2003 and each time used the XP drivers. Never had a problem.

Comment: just to be specific, what are some of the named brands and when you say "no-name", does this include any foreign sales from Ebay?

Comment: The only actual brand I can remember is Logitec. The "no-name" units, a couple of different models, were purchased at a street market for next to nothing. Even the driver CDs had no label but included what I later learned to be generic chip drivers. The cameras do look just like those I've seen commonly on eBay.